# How to get Jenkins env vars from another job's console log output and use as params?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins multiphase job with two phases.  Phase 1 is a build and the output is printed to the console logs.  Here's an example of the log output:

```
team=justiceLeague
member=batman
```

For Phase 2, I would like to be able to parse this console log and get values of "team" and "member", which will be used as params for phase2's jobs.

Is there some way to do this?  Thank you.

Comment: I've answered a similar question here

**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785510/shell-script-to-accept-jenkins-job-name-and-triggers-that-job-form-commandline/22787039#22787039**

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to get a job's build output as raw text by calling the following:

`curl http://jenkins-host/job/job-name/number/consoleText`

Once you have that, you can parse out anything you want.

Also, look into the Jenkins API:

`http://jenkins-host/api`

to get other options of getting information from Jenkins.

I hope this helps.